# R: Parse data.frame string variable into multiple variables

Tags: r, parsing

I have data gathered through Amazon's Mechnical Turk that has a column vector called "LifeTimeApprovalRate". The column contains information

```
head(ES$LifetimeApprovalRate)
[1] [1] "100% (32/32)" "50% (16/32)" "100% (11/11)" "100% (4/4)"`
```

I would like to create three new variables using this information:

```
 ES$rate: "100%" "50%" "100%" "100%" 
 ES$approve: "32" "16" "11" "4"
 ES$total: "32" "32" "11" "4"
```

I am afraid just about anything I try creates these monstrous lists which are difficult to manage into anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tidyr**'s `separate` is also handy for this sort of thing:

```
library(tidyr)
> dat <- data.frame(x = 1:4,y = c("100% (32/32)", "50% (16/32)", "100% (11/11)", "100% (4/4)"))
> separate(dat,y,c("rate","approve","total"),sep = "[()/ ]+",extra = "drop")
  x rate approve total
1 1 100%      32    32
2 2  50%      16    32
3 3 100%      11    11
4 4 100%       4     4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try `strsplit`

```
  nm1 <- c('rate', 'approve', 'total')
  ES[nm1] <- do.call(rbind,
             strsplit(as.character(ES$LifetimeApprovalRate),'[()/ ]+'))

  ES[nm1[-1]] <- lapply(ES[nm1[-1]], as.numeric) 
  ES
  #    LifetimeApprovalRate rate approve total
  #1         100% (32/32) 100%      32    32
  #2          50% (16/32)  50%      16    32
  #3         100% (11/11) 100%      11    11
  #4           100% (4/4) 100%       4     4
```

A similar option using the `devel` version of data.table i.e. `v1.9.5` is below. Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Here, we use `tstrsplit` to split the column 'LifetimeApprovalRate' and assign the output columns to new columns ('nm1').  There is also option `type.convert=TRUE` to convert the column classes.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(ES)[, (nm1):=tstrsplit(LifetimeApprovalRate,'[()/ ]+', type.convert=TRUE)]
 #   LifetimeApprovalRate rate approve total
 #1:         100% (32/32) 100%      32    32
 #2:          50% (16/32)  50%      16    32
 #3:         100% (11/11) 100%      11    11
 #4:           100% (4/4) 100%       4     4
```

#### data

```
 ES <-  structure(list(LifetimeApprovalRate = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 
 3L), .Label = c("100% (11/11)", "100% (32/32)", "100% (4/4)", 
 "50% (16/32)"), class = "factor")), .Names = "LifetimeApprovalRate",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```